# How to rewrite URL in ASP.NET 4 Web Forms and hide some parameters

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, webforms, url-routing

I have web page in asp.net 4 Web forms, that generate this URLs:

```
http://www.myweb.com/Default.aspx?mode=articles&seo_name=my-best-article
```

and I want to show url in this format:

```
http://www.myweb.com/my-best-article
```

but i need to access original query string (mode and seo_url).

Now Im using this solution:

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute(
        "default-page",
        "{mode}/{seo_name}",
        "~/Default.aspx"
    );
}
```

but it shows both parametrs and I want only seo_name.

How can I do this?

Comment: Where do you expect `mode` to come from if you don't have it in your url?

Comment: It is my question if it is possible?

Comment: Well, if you need the parameter it needs to be passed to the server somehow. If you don't want this value to be in the url you could pass it by post or session for example but the server needs to know it!